# Making sure that a malicious apk isn't talking to my server

Tags: java, php, android, security

I'm trying to make sure that someone can't recompile my obfuscated application and then send malicious data to my server. I am doing an SSLed PHP_POST of my application's versionCode and packageName. These POSTED variables are all encrypted via asymmetrical encryption along with signature verification which will be changed per every version upgrade. I have thought of using checksums but those methods are not supported officially by Google and research has shown that they are not error-proof meaning that they could potentially disrupt legitimate users.

On top of all of this is a ban-on-site via IP/Mac Address/IMEI/Serial/Android_ID/etc when something is detected that is 100% not legit.

I understand that nothing could be 100% secured and the difference between a good security and a bad one is the time/money/effort it takes to break a security is valued higher than the item being protected by the security. With this in mind, are there any other methods I could use to protect my application or any ideas I should implement to add onto current security?

On a side-note, how easy is it to decompile/recompile an apk(jar) that's been obfuscated and would it be easier once its been done once? (aka, it doesn't matter how many times I change the key because the application is already compromised and the decompiler can simply look at the same spot where my last key was)

Comment: The common solution is to require users to login which is verified on the server before granting access. Is there a reason why you can't do this?

Comment: Yes, I feel that this is a hassle to the users. The specific function i'm protecting requires a token to use it which the user can buy. Upon buying they would receive a tokenID hashed with their identifier.

I don't think using a login system would help either. I'm trying to identify a decompiled version of my apk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, first, don't do your own crypto. If you are properly(!) doing SSL that is  probably enough to protect data in transit against tampering, etc. What you need to do is authenticate your app somehow which is generally tricky, because you need to keep the credentials in the app. There are different ways around that, but currently the standard (and Google-endorsed way) is to use Google Play services to obtain a token and verify it in your server app. Details here: http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html

This not perfect, but is probably better than most non-standard solutions you can come up with.

Decompiling is generally easy, and obfuscation doesn't change much, since it is trivial to find the places where you are calling system APIs (to get MAC addresses, hash, encrypt, etc.)